# Why is there a loop in this dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

Is it possible to iterate the list in side the dictionary? Looks like a complex syntax.

```
URLS = ['http://www.foxnews.com/',
    'http://www.cnn.com/',
    'http://europe.wsj.com/',
    'http://www.bbc.co.uk/',
    'http://some-made-up-domain.com/']

future_to_url = {executor.submit(load_url, url, 60): url for url in URLS}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking at a [dictionary comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays); it builds a dictionary from a loop.

It is equivalent to:

```
future_to_url = {}
for url in URLS:
    future_to_url[executor.submit(load_url, url, 60)] = url
```

but spelt more succinctly.

The same can be done to produce a list:

```
[executor.submit(load_url, url, 60) for url in URLS]
```

or sets:

```
{executor.submit(load_url, url, 60) for url in URLS}
```

or produce the elements lazily in a generator expression:

```
(executor.submit(load_url, url, 60) for url in URLS)
```

See the [*List Comprehensions* section](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) of the Python tutorial, and onwards, where the other comprehensions are explained.

Dict comprehensions require Python 2.7 or newer; if you need to port this back to older Python versions, you'd use the generator expression syntax inside a `dict()` function to produce `(key, value)` tuples:

```
dict((executor.submit(load_url, url, 60), url) for url in URLS)
```